# Можно ли добавить в раскрывающийся список более одного блока в Таплинк?

Tags: javascript

Раскрывашка стандартной кнопкой

Создаёте кнопку со значением "javascript:void(0)" вместо ссылки (без кавычек)
Снизу от кнопки делаете любой блок, который должен открываться
Между этими блоками добавляете код

```
<div class="exp"></div>
```

В самый низ страницы добавляете код

```
<script>

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.exp')).map((exp) => {

var expandbtn = exp.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.previousSibling;

expandbtn.classList.add('expandbtn')

 var expandedcontent = expandbtn.nextSibling.nextSibling;

 expandedcontent.classList.add('not-expanded')

 var expanded = false;

 expandbtn.onclick = function () {

if (expanded === false) {expandedcontent.classList.remove('not-expanded')

 expanded = true}

 else {expandedcontent.classList.add('not-expanded')

 expanded = false}

}

 });

</script>

<style>

.not-expanded {

 height: 0px;

 padding: 0px;

 opacity: 0;

 transform: translate(0px, -30px);

 transition: all 0.2s linear;

 }

.block-item {

 transition: all 0.2s linear;

}

 .expandbtn {

position: relative;

}

 .expandbtn::after {

 position: absolute;

content: "Подробнее";

 right: 10px;

 bottom: -5px;

 font-size: 14px;

 color: #eee;

 background: tomato;

 border-radius: 6px;

 padding: 3px 7px;

 

}

</style>
```

Готово! Теперь у вас открывается скрытый блок по нажатию кнопки!

Но так работает только с одним блоком, к примеру если под кнопкой разместить блок с текстом он будет его скрывать и показывать, однако если туда добавить кнопку действия, то скрывается только текст, а кнопка остается статичной.

Что нужно изменить в коде, чтобы можно было скрывать 2 и более блоков